# How create Sharepoint online site with custom template?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, client-object-model, sharepoint-hosted-app

I need to create site in SharePoint Online from SharePoint hosted app. I used code like this:

```
var webCreationInfo = new SP.WebCreationInformation();
        webCreationInfo.set_webTemplate('STS#0');
```

But now I have a problem because I need use my own template. How can I get code for own template in SharePoint Online?

Comment: Did you try http://joranmarkx.wordpress.com/2013/07/18/how-to-apply-a-custom-web-template-using-jsom-javascript-sharepoint-object-model/

Comment: @Aanchal Thank you. I think it would be working, but i don't know how to get feature id? Could you tell it to me ?

Comment: How are you deploying your custom template?

Comment: @Aanchal i created site and than saved it like template. After it i choose this template when create new site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you like to use the title of your template, you could get it with an extra call to the the getAvailableWebTemplates on the web. Something like this:

```
var createSubSite = function(templateName) {
        var webCreationInfo = new SP.WebCreationInformation();
         webCreationInfo.set_title(dataForSiteCreate[i].clientInfo.ClientName);
        webCreationInfo.set_description(dataForSiteCreate[i].clientInfo.ClientDescription);
        webCreationInfo.set_language(1033);            
        webCreationInfo.set_url(hostname);
        webCreationInfo.set_useSamePermissionsAsParentSite(true);
        webCreationInfo.set_webTemplate(templateName);

        var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

        var newWeb = clientContext.get_web().get_webs().add(webCreationInfo);

        clientContext.load(newWeb);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function() {
            console.log("Done");
            }, function(sender,args) { 
            console.log("failed. Message:" + args.get_message());
        });     
}

var getTemplateName = function(templateName) {
    var dfd = new $.Deferred(); 
    var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var templates = clientContext.get_web().getAvailableWebTemplates(1033, false);
    clientContext.load(templates);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function() {
        var templateGuidName;

        for (var template in templates.get_data()) {
                if (templates.itemAt(template).get_title() === templateName) {
                    templateGuidName = templates.itemAt(template).get_name();
                    break;
                }
            }   
        dfd.resolve(templateGuidName);

     }, function() { dfd.reject(); });

    return dfd.promise();

}

SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", "SP.ClientContext", function () {
    getTemplateName("TitleOfYourTemplateHere").done(function(template) {
        createSubSite(template);    
    }); 
});
```

Some error handling etc is needed, but it should work. I have used jquery deferred in the example, so that's needed.

Answer (score 1):

Using Custom Template:

```
function CreateWebsite(title, description, webUrl, templateTitle)
{    
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    context.load(web);
    var webTemplates = web.getAvailableWebTemplates(1033,false);
    context.load(webTemplates);
    context.executeQueryAsync(function(){
            var enumerator = webTemplates.getEnumerator();
            var customTemplate;
            while(enumerator.moveNext())
            {
                var webTemplate = enumerator.get_current();
                var webTitle = webTemplate.get_title();
                if(webTitle == templateTitle) // templateTitle = Custom Tempalte Title
                {
                    customTemplate = webTemplate.get_name();
                    break;
                }
            }                
            var webCreationInformation = new SP.WebCreationInformation();
            webCreationInformation.set_title(title);
            webCreationInformation.set_description(description);
            webCreationInformation.set_language(1033);
            webCreationInformation.set_url(webUrl);
            webCreationInformation.set_useSamePermissionsAsParentSite(true);
            webCreationInformation.set_webTemplate(customTemplate);
            web.get_webs().add(webCreationInformation);
            context.executeQueryAsync(function(){
                alert('Website created successfully.');
            }, 
            function(sender, args){ 
                alert(args.get_message());
                });
        }, 
        function(sender, args){ 
            alert(args.get_message())
        }
    );
}
```